# How I do text detection from image using google vision api?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, google-cloud-vision

I new the Android code side and I have a project.

I want text detection from ımage using google vision api, but I cannot.

I search the internet but I can't find enough information and I know I should use Json(AsynTack).

Just want this not face detection,logo detection.

How can I do this, can you suggest anything?

Answer (score 2):

The [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request) consists of a single endpoint (https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images) that supports one HTTP request method (annotate). Here is a sample JSON request:

POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate

```
{
  "requests":[
    {
      "image":{
        "content":"change_this_to_the_path_of_your_image"
      },
      "features":[
        {
          "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
          "maxResults":1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fork of Google sample code, working mainly for text detection.

https://github.com/JackFan-Z/cloud-vision/tree/fda5e83447f9e69cf8a18112e0fced1da928f3d8

Just use **Android Studio** to open the project in the folder

`cloud-vision/android/CloudVision/`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you really need:

***//Google code labs for mobile vision*** 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0

Do let me know if this info helps.

Comment: Yeah ı already see that even ı use but this app use Real-Time.I want this;         for example ı send image to Cloud Api and response is  a text.This like https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/requests-and-responses but ı dont know so much json jobs